# Receiving a WCF callback service from a ASP.NET web app hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-6, xbap, wcf-callbacks

I have been working on this issue for a couple of days now.

The problem has 3 working parts.
I have a ASP.NET site , WCF IIS hosted service and WPF xbap app.

What I'm trying to do is pass variables from the ASP.NET site to the WPF xbap app. So I have setup a WCF service with a wsDualHttpBinding and using callbacks to notify the ASP.NET and the xbap.

Now when I host the WCF service in IIS 6 on our server and run ASP.NET hosting in VS2012 iisexpress locally and xbap locally. It works fine. 
But as soon as I publish the ASP.NET site to the IIS 6 on our server, callback are never received by the ASP.NET app. Both are in the application pool.

Is there a setting, or something I need to be looking for to have the ASP.NET to keep open the listening port for the callbacks? The XBAP is still receiving the callbacks, no problem.

The service config is as follows: (note I have maxed out the buffers because of simplicity for the moment to rule that out)

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
       <add initializeData="web_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
     <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The service has methods where clients will subscribe to callback lists. Then methods will increment through the list to send the invoke the callbacks.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallback))]
public interface IVisualisationService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SubscribeToRedenderHoles(string address);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SubscribeToEditSelectedHoles(string address);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SubscribeToShowHoles(string address);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RedenderHoles(Hole3D[] holes, string address, int channelhashcode);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void EditSelectedHoles(Guid[] holesIds, string address);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ShowHoles(string address);


}

public interface IClientCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnRenderHoles(Hole3D[] holes);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnEditSelectedHoles(Guid[] holesIds);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnShowHoles(int channelhashcode);
}
```

Below is the WCF Service header, Ive skipped putting in the methods.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class VisualisationService : IVisualisationService
{
```

Now for the ASP.NET Client web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" >
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://hims.mecha.com/VisualisationWcfService/VisualisationService.svc"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService"
            contract="VisualisationServiceReference.IVisualisationService"
            name="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then XBAP app client app.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService"     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" >
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://hims.mecha.com/VisualisationWcfService/VisualisationService.svc"        
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService"
            contract="VisualisationService.IVisualisationService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IVisualisationService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In both clients I have used the Add Service Reference method, to add the WCF to both the ASP.NET and XBAP projects. 
I have setup both clients to have the code and of course handle the methods for each callback.

```
sealed class VisualisationManager : VisualisationService.IVisualisationServiceCallback
```

I know it looks a bit long winded, but I wanted to show as much about the problem as I could. I am completely lost, why it would work fine locally but not when hosted in IIS 6.

Comment: Are any of the contracts marked IsOneWay=true using a Context object, such as OperationContext.Current?  Also, do the calls work as expected with IsOneWay set to false?

Answer (score 0):

late answer but in case someone like me who get to this question through the Big G.

I had similar issue and the solution for me is to add a CallbackBehavior to the class which implement the callback interface (in your case; IClientCallback). like this:

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ClientCallback : IClientCallback
...
```

Hope this help.